# Store getcwd on a struct on a function

Tags: c

```
typedef struct 
{
  char Path[100];
} DirectoryInformation;

void Getskelutofdirectorie(char * dir, int lvl) 
{
    DirectoryInformation DI[100];
    char cwd[1024];

    //Search recursive

    // where I want to put the path on the struct to use on main

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    strcpy(DI[0].Path, cwd);
}

int main(void) 
{
    DirecoryInformation DI[100];
    printf("%s", DI[0].Path);

}
```

I can print the path but if i use on main function will work.

Can somebody help me out?

It executes without error but when I print out make segmentation fault

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have a buffer of size 1024 for the `getcwd` result, only to copy it to a buffer of size 100, ignoring whether or not it will fit.  For that matter, why copy it at all?  Why not just place it there in the first place?  As it is now, you will have memory corruption if the path is ever longer than 99 characters.  You should never write code like that.

Comment: In `main` function `DirecoryInformation DI[100]; printf("%s", DI[0].Path);` is using an uninitialised variable. Even without a segfault you'll print nothing useful. Also the similarly named `DirectoryInformation DI[100];` in the other function is a local variable which goes out of scope on leaving the function. Storing a string in it, then exiting the function will take you nowhere.

Comment: Tom Karzes thanks for the advice gonna keep on my mind

Comment: You are even not calling `Getskelutofdirectorie`. This code will never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code invokes *undefined behavior* by using value of variable `DI` having automatic storage duration and not initialized, which is indeterminate.

Call the function with passing pointer to the struct to store the data, then store there.

```
typedef struct
{
  char Path[100];
} DirectoryInformation;

void Getskelutofdirectorie(DirectoryInformation * DI, char * dir, int lvl)
{
    char cwd[100]; // cwd was too long, so there was risk of buffer overrun when copying

    //Search recursive

    //where i want to put the path on the struct to use on main

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    strcpy(DI[0].Path, cwd);
}

int main(void) 
{
    DirectoryInformation DI[100] = {{""}}; // initialize for in case the function fails to set values
    Getskelutofdirectorie(DI, NULL, 0); // pass proper parameter
    printf("%s", DI[0].Path);

}
```

Comment: Thanks alot  in my real program i call the function on main i just forget to copy. The problem was the getskelotdireotirie  the parametheres i forget to use the struct one. BTW should i use always strncopy?